# Depth of discharge:Battery

Tags: batteries

Am a bit confused about battery terminology,to be specific about discharge capacity,hence a quick question.
What is meant by depth of discharge?How does one know if a 12V,7.5Ah battery is discharged to a depth of 50%? Does it mean that it has been supplying 7.5A for 30mins ?

Answer (score 4):

In a word, yes.

Depth Of Discharge (DOD) is the "opposite" of State Of Charge (SOC)
i.e. DOD = 100% - SOC.

Typically it relates to how many cycles the battery will last for. For example, if a cycle means discharging to 30% SOC (70% DOD), the battery will last for fewer cycles than if you only discharged to 60% SOC (40% DOD) each time.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially yes.

But the discharge rate (7.5A) has to be compatible with the way the capacity (7.5 Ah) was measured.

The fine print may tell you the discharge rate at which capacity was measured - if it says capacity is 7.5Ah at 1C discharge, then your guess is correct.

1C means it's charged or discharged in 1 hour; C/10 means it's charged or discharged in 10 hours, 10C means it's charged or discharged in 6 minutes (1/10 hour).

But if its capacity (7.5 Ah) is measured at the C/20 rate (common in lead-acid batteries) the battery datasheet will give another (reduced) capacity for the C rate - possibly 5 Ah - in which case 7.5A for 30 minutes (3.75Ah) leaves you 75% discharged.

So, yes in theory, but read the battery datasheet to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

> How does one know if a 12V,7.5Ah battery is discharged to a depth of 50%?
>   Does it mean that it has been supplying 7.5A for 30mins ?

In one word **Never.**

If you use an SLA battery faster than the 20 h "standard" discharge rate down to the fastest rate @22.5A then your capacity declines to 50%. or ~ 3.7Ah.

**This means you only get 7.5Ah when using 0.375A for 20 h.**

The battery curve that your supplier specs will indicate the varying cuttoff voltage for each discharge rate, time duration and the product of constant current and time that is your available Ah rate. This only applies only when NEW and will degrade slowly towards end of life then rapidly decline to zero.

[image]

This supplier indicates @7.5A you get 7.8V (cuttoff) in 40 minutes for 0% SoC.
**That means 40/60min *7.5A= = 5Ah**
You started with 12.5V*7.5A ~ 94W output
and ended with 7.8V*7.5A=~58W ,
so your output power dropped to 62% of the initial power output.